HTTP 405 Error for POST Requests on IIS with ASP.NET Web API
I'm facing an HTTP 405 error when making POST requests to my ASP.NET Web API hosted on IIS. The same setup works fine on my local development server but fails when deployed to IIS. I am using a proxy in my Vite configuration to hide the port for security reasons.
Environment:

Frontend: Vue.js (SPA using Vite)
Backend: ASP.NET Web API
Server: IIS

Vite Configuration:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import { quasar, transformAssetUrls } from "@quasar/vite-plugin";

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 8080,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://mydomain:8081/api",
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: { transformAssetUrls },
    }),
    quasar({
      sassVariables: "@/quasar-variables.scss",
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});

Web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ApiHandler" path="api/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler, System.Web.Http.WebHost" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="SPA Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <verbs>
          <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
          <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
          <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
          <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

ASP.NET Web API Controller:
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Auth/Login")]
public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
{
    // Your login logic here
    return Ok();
}

When making a POST request to https://mydomain/api/Auth/Login using Postman, I receive the following error:
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

I Verified that WebDAV is disabled.Then ensured that web.config allows POST requests. Confirmed that the API endpoint is correctly set up in the ASP.NET Web API and restarted the IIS multiple times.
IIS Log: 2024-08-06 01:43:13 192.141.24.2 POST /api/Auth/Login - 3000 - 170.224.24.21 PostmanRuntime/7.40.0 - 405 0 1 2
What could be causing the HTTP 405 error for POST requests, and how can I resolve this issue to allow POST requests on my IIS-hosted ASP.NET Web API, while maintaining the proxy setup to hide the port for security reasons?

Do other HTTP methods have similar problem? I Verified that WebDAV is disabled. How did you disable module WebDAV? Try adding the following section to Web.config and suggest that you use FRT to track for more information.
<system.webServer><modules><remove name="WebDAVModule" /></modules><handlers><remove name="WebDAV" /></handlers></system.webServer>
